# Diretório de arquivo

Tags: java, arquivo, diretório

Olá, estou fazendo um programa em java na qual preciso abrir um arquivo e lê-lo. Porém quando eu estou tentando colocar o caminho do arquivo, ele não encontra tal arquivo e assim fico com o erro de Null Pointer Exception. O código é o seguinte:

```
 public File[] returnFiles() 
{
    File f = new File("/tests");
    File[] filesArray = f.listFiles();
    return filesArray;
}
```

Alguém poderia me dizer porquê não estou dando conta de encontrar o arquivo neste diretório? Obs: Estou usando a IDE Netbeans, dizem que deve ser problema dele por não estar sendo encontrado.

Desde já, agradeço.

Comment: Então, o caminho é este mesmo "/tests". Ou eu teria que colocar o caminho desde a raiz?

Comment: Ela é uma sub pasta de todo o projeto:
Interpreter/tests

Comment: Se você apresentar o caminho relativo como no código, o netbeans vai procurar, por padrão, a pasta na raiz do projeto. Ex.: `NetbeansProjects/seuProjeto/tests`, se não tiver desse jeito, você precisa passar o caminho completo.

Comment: Lembrando que ela está localizada na Área de Trabalho. Seria isso?

Comment: Diego, fiz o passo que disse. Porém acusa o mesmo erro.

Comment: Adicione a pilha de erros completa pra ver se o problema está na linha mencionada.

Comment: Diego, descobri o erro. É que eu deveria colocar o caminho desde o home. Erro bobo aqui, mas obrigado por ter ajudado.

Comment: Foi o que te falei, sobre caminho relativo e absoluto(completo ate a raiz). :)

Comment: É, eu que não interpretei a sua frase direito. Desculpe! rs

Comment: Sem problemas, manusear sistema de arquivos em java as vezes enche o saco com esses nullpointer mesmo  kkkk

Comment: Concordo, kkkkkkkk.